# IA mapping - Should I include filters in the IA map?

Tags: information-architecture

I'm creating an app and there's no need for a search bar, just filters to make the navigation easier to find. Should I include them the filters in the IA document?

Comment: This question is getting (unnecessarily) downvoted because it's of low quality. There's really just too little here to go on, and vague question in the UX realm all have the same answer - it depends. If you want a good answer you'll need to expand a bit. Who is your IA map for?  How will you represent these filters? and most importantly, What is your perceived problem here? You wouldn't ask "Should I keep my valuables in a safe place?", so why isn't putting these filters in the map a slam dunk idea?

Answer (score 0):

The IA document is a reference document for business users, developers and graphic designers. It shows agreed upon standards from font styles to form fields to how a search works.

If your project doesn't use a search field it may still be useful to have a section for search and clearly state that this project does not use a search field.

The filters should, without a doubt, be in the IA document.  People will inevitably have questions regarding the filters and how the results are to be displayed.